# How can I create a Splunk App dynamically by Splunk Java or C# SDK

Tags: splunk

Basically, we create Splunk App on the web, but now we need to create a App dynamically from our client program. Can Splunk's Java or C# SDK supports this feature?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Java and C# Splunk SDKs are just wrappers for the REST API, but do not provide all of the functionality.

I believe that app creation falls into the category of something that is in the REST API, but not in the SDKs.

You can see everything the C# SDK provides [here](http://dev.splunk.com/view/csharp-sdk/SP-CAAAEPK#whattodo)

You could always access the REST API directly in your C# app. [This link](http://answers.splunk.com/answers/9529/trying-to-create-an-application-with-splunks-restful-api) shows how to create an app through the REST API.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the links. Let me give a try.